# cd using bash rematch and results of pwd

Tags: bash

I'm looking to run `pwd`, and if the contents include "/Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser/", then redirect to ~/, followed by whatever the rest of the contents of `pwd` were. So for example if pwd returned:

```
/Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser/Desktop/folder1/folder2/
```

This bash script would cd into:

```
~/Desktop/folder1/folder2/
```

What I have so far is this, but I can't seem to get the match group to display properly:

```
[[ $(pwd) =~ \/Volumes\/Storage\/Users\/testuser\/(.*) ]] && cd "~/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are interested in an alternative solution.

I suggest the following using shell parameter expansion.

```
PREFIX="/Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser/"
PWD=`pwd`

[[ ${PWD} =~ ${PREFIX}* ]] && cd ~/"${PWD#${PREFIX}}"
```

The form `${PWD#${PREFIX}}` removes `${PREFIX}` at the beginning of `${PWD}`.

Comment: This seems promising, but I can't seem to get it to run in a script. If I call each command separately on a line it works fine though.

Comment: To expand on that last comment, if I put it in a script, it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: probably you are in the wrong directory and the conditional fails. Put some `echo`'s in there for debugging purposes. I tested it and for me it works just fine

Answer (score 2):

The tilde can't be quoted, otherwise `cd` will see a literal `~` character.

```
cd ~/"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

You also do not need to escape the slashes, for what it's worth.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that to no avail. It just returns the contents of ~/ (e.g. `/Users/testuser`), without any of the bash rematch.

Comment: Or use $HOME instead of ~ inside the doulbe quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be esacping the slashes in your regex.

Also, the `~` will not work correctly in a string, as John Kugelman mentioned.

```
if [[ $(pwd) =~ /Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser/(.*) ]]; then
    cd "$HOME/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Comment: As I also mentioned to @John_Kugelman, that only cd's into `~/`, with no regex matches.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?

If a user tries to `cd` to `/Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser/Desktop/folder1/folder2/` and their HOME directory is `/home/bob`, they should `cd` to `/home/bob/Desktop/folder1/folder2` instead?

What if `/home/bob/Desktop/folder1/folder2` doesn't exist?

Here's a function to replace `cd` with one that munges the directory you're CD'ing to. Alias `_cd` to `cd` and you're all set.

The same basic thing could be done in other shell scripts if you're not munging the `cd` command.

I'm using the `${parameter#word}` syntax to remove the `$BAD_DIR` prefix. I use glob matching to see if the directory has the bad directory as a prefix.

And then I use `HOME_DIR=~` to set my true HOME directory. I don't know what happens if a user munges `$HOME` if it changes `~` or not. However, this allows me to use quotes in my directory name.

I probably should check `$PWD` to make sure they're not already there, and verify if this is a relative `cd` vs one where a full path is given. However, that's easy enough to add in. This should be enough to get you going.

```
function _cd {
    cd_to_dir="$1"
    BAD_DIR="/Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser"
    if [[ $cd_to_dir = $BAD_DIR* ]]
    then
        HOME_DIR=~
        cd_to_dir="$HOME_DIR/${cd_to_dir#${BAD_DIR}}"
    fi
    \cd "$cd_to_dir"
}

alias cd=_cd
```

This works ***on my computer***. I have BASH, but I also set `extglob` and a few other things. This ***SHOULD*** work without `extglob` set, but if it doesn't add these lines:

```
function _cd {
    cd_to_dir="$1"
    BAD_DIR="/Volumes/Storage/Users/testuser"
    is_extglob_set=$(shopt -q extglob)
    [ $is_extglob_set ] || shopt -s extglob
    if [[ $cd_to_dir = $BAD_DIR* ]]
    then
        HOME_DIR=~
        cd_to_dir="$HOME_DIR/${cd_to_dir#${BAD_DIR}}"
    fi
    [ $is_extglob_set ] || shopt -u extglob
    \cd $cd_to_dir
}

alias cd=_cd
```